# How to import a string from a CSV file with spaces

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, csv-import

I have a CSV file with lots of rows like the following:

```
01-01-2013 02:00 AM;4866,78;string1;1;3
01-01-2013 03:00 AM;4866,78;string2;1;3
```

I want to import it to a table with the following structure:

```
+---------+---------------------+---------+--------------+
|  ID     | Data 1              |Data 2   | ... and so on|
+---------+---------------------+---------+--------------+
| 1       |01-01-2013 02:00 AM  | 4866,78 | ...          |
+---------+---------------------+---------+--------------+
| 2       |01-01-2013 03:00 AM  | 4866,78 | ...          |
+---------+---------------------+---------+--------------+
```

The structure is set. ID is auto increment. I have the following import options:
[image: CSV Import options]

What settings do I need to undertake to get Data 1, without loosing the spaces inbetween?
Right now I tried
Spalten getrennt mit: ;
Spalten eingeschlossen von: 
Spalten escaped with: 
Zielen enden auf: auto
Column names: Data 1, Data2, ...

My result inside the DB looks like this unfortunately:

```
+---------+-------------------+---------+--------------+
|  ID     | Data 1            |Data 2   | ... and so on|
+---------+-------------------+---------+--------------+
| 1       |01-01-201302:00AM  | 4866,78 | ...          |
+---------+-------------------+---------+--------------+
| 2       |01-01-201303:00AM  | 4866,78 | ...          |
+---------+-------------------+---------+--------------+
```

I lost the intended and needed spaces inside Data 1 Column.

Comment: What is the data type of the column for Data 1? Varchar? Text? Datetime?

Comment: its varchar. but i could change it to text.

Comment: No, that shouldn't make a difference in this case. Additionally, I'm unable to reproduce your problem with a few modifications. I don't have an ID column, because having a column without a corresponding field in the CSV file tends to confuse the import parser, and I changed the "Columns separated with:" to a semicolon `;` instead of the default comma `,`.  What phpMyAdmin version do you have?

Comment: hmm... I'm using 4.0.9.